# Emacs setup for rails development in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

I am a seasoned .net developer and using VS.net all the time. Now, I would like to learn [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) using Emacs. Since I'm pretty new to Linux, it would be great if someone show me step by step tutorial to setup emacs for RoR develpment.

Comment: Are you totally new to Emacs?

Comment: @Bastien yes. but I want to learn Emacs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a 5 part series on how to set that up: http://sodonnell.wordpress.com/the-emacs-newbie-guide-for-rails/

Also, here is a screencast on how to do it: http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-and-rails-on-emacs-screencast-281.html

Good luck and enjoy! I am also a .Net dev delving into RoR

Answer (score 1):

I use `vim` personally (as do most other Rails coders I know), but the [Rails site](http://rubyonrails.org/download) points here: http://dima-exe.ru/rails-on-emacs.

That seems to be dead, though.  Here it is on archive.org:  http://web.archive.org/web/20071014011209/http://dima-exe.ru/rails-on-emacs.  You can also try http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyOnRails and the forks of http://github.com/tomtt/emacs-rails on GitHub.

I hope this helps.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [small blog post](http://devcraft.wordpress.com/2008/07/19/using-emacs-for-rails-development-the-perfect-setup/) on the subject I wrote some time ago.